# Select one column value for other columns based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table like given below structure, I need to write a query to fetch result like achived month comnet retaine for all remaining months from the table based on a condition if the actual value is greater than or equal to target then select that particular month `comments` value for remaining months too.My table structure is

[image: Table]

I am Expecting the result like the below structure.

[image: Result]

Here in June actual value is 100 and comment 'Closed' after thet user will not enter anything(Actual or comments) since actual meets target. so i need to display the commment 'Closed' in all remaining months(July-Dec)

Comment: If `Target` & `Actual` value is `NULL`, do we need to consider that row? Also, your expected result looks similar to your table structure except for comments column, is it expected?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh no need to consider the null values.once the target value meets the actual the select that month comments to remaining months. the table structure also the same

Comment: Your expected output is not clear, Please add clarity

Comment: expected output is once the actual meets the target then take the comments from that purticular month and display it for all remaining month

Comment: @Jzl You need to update existing table or just select query?

Comment: @SukhpalSingh Select quey

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is not clear, Please add clarity. 
How about this? -

```
SELECT *
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE MONTHS_ID IN (SELECT MONTHS_ID FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ACTUAL_VALUE >= TARGET)
```

Do you want to aggregate comments by Months_ID?

```
SELECT MONTHS_ID,
       LISTAGG(COMMENTS, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY COMMENTS) AS COMMENTS
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE MONTHS_ID IN (SELECT MONTHS_ID  FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ACTUAL_VALUE >= TARGET)
 GROUP BY MONTHS_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a  where based on you filter condition

```
    select a.comment 
    from your_table_with_commen a 
    where a.comment is not null
    and a.target is not null 
    and a.target <= a.actual
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output isn't very clear. But if I got it correctly, then you can achieve the desired result using below query(may not be best performing):

```
with commentValue as (
select month_id, comments from your_table where actual_value = ( select max(target) 
from your_table) 
)
select yt.target,yt.month_id,
case when yt.month_id >= cv.month_id then cv.comments else yt.comments end as 
comments,
yt.actual_value
from your_table yt
join commentValue cv on 1 = 1
```

Comment: in 6 th month user enter the coment. If I am exicuting the query in december i need to get the above result. after 6 th month there is no values in comment column., so by default last entered value should be replace for null in select query

Comment: What does last entered value mean? Also, does my answer solve your original question?

Comment: Simply I need to display previous month comment to all upcoming month commnet column. your query is not solved yet

Comment: This isn't same as the question you asked.

Comment: I have modified my question

Answer (score 0):

From the explanation, seems you need nothing more than this :

```
Select month, nvl(comment,'Closed') as comment, target, actual
  From tableDemands;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to write a query to fetch result like achived month comnet retaine for all remaining months from the table based on a condition if the actual value is greater than or equal to target then select that particular month comments value for remaining months too.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65e07f/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( month, "COMMENT", target, actual ) AS
  SELECT  1, 'initiated',          NULL,    5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  2, 'feb',                NULL,    6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  3, 'Mar- On going',      NULL,   10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  4, 'Apr- work On going', NULL,   20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  5, 'May- Ongoing',       NULL,   50 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  6, 'closed',             NULL,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  7, NULL,                 NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  8, NULL,                 NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  9, NULL,                  100, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, NULL,                 NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, NULL,                 NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, NULL,                 NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT month,
       "COMMENT",
       max_target As target,
       actual
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX( target ) OVER () AS max_target
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE actual >= max_target
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65e07f/3/0)**:

```
| MONTH | COMMENT | TARGET | ACTUAL |
|-------|---------|--------|--------|
|     6 |  closed |    100 |    100 |
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to replace a null comment with the last non-null comment. Use `LAST_VALUE` for this:

```
select
  month,
  last_value(comment ignore nulls) over (order by month) as comment,
  target,
  actual
from mytable
order by month;
```